# creating qrcode in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, qr-code

can anyone give me some idea about qrcode lib for wp7 ?I have found a lib here: http://qrcodegenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets
i can generate qr code within string of 26 character...it occurs an exception generating if the string is more than 26 character!

```
using Huyn.QRCode;

var generator = new QRCodeGenerator
{
    QRCodeVersion = 9,
    QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeGenerator.ERRORCORRECTION.H
};
    imgQRCode.Source = generator.Generate("Hello, World!");
```

i need a lib which will create a qr image from a large string!Please give some idea !

Comment: Are you asking for help with your exception? (if so, what is the error you're getting?) Or are you asking for an alternative? (If so, what else have you found/looked for already?)

Comment: i need an alternative way to generate qr image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the C# ZXing port 2.0.
I'm using it in a app now, and it's working perfectly.

See this post on how I generate the QR code:

[Generating QR code on Windows Phone 7.1 using ZXing 2.0 C# Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293726/generating-qr-code-on-windows-phone-7-1-using-zxing-2-0-c-sharp-port)

Cheers.

Comment: http://qrcodegenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets this one is also working good!