# how to create QR code in windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, qr-code

Please tell how to generate QR code in Windows Phone 7.1. I have tried this url[ThomasVestergaard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293726/generating-qr-code-on-windows-phone-7-1-using-zxing-2-0-c-sharp-port)

I'm using Silverlight_ZXing_Core version v2.0.50727 library.

But When I used code from above link I have following issue
1.System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not contain a definition for 'SetPixel' and no extension method 'SetPixel' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please tell me how to resolve this as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library. It has extension methods for `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` in addition to other useful stuff.